# finding time difference with 1 cell

Tags: excel, csv, time

I recently pulled a huge amount of data into a csv file, as a result a large amount of data is being formatted like this:

xx:xx-xx:xx - 'text'

The problem i'm having is this is all in one cell, I've tried looking online without much luck so basically wanted to know if it's even possible to find the time difference between xx:xx-xx:xx even if they're stored on the same cell? If not, is there a way to split these times into different cells en mass?

edit:

I've managed to remove the text from the cell, I now am left with 1 cell containing ranges similar to: [image]

Comment: I sugges you to post some real data to get an appropiate answer. About *is there a way to split these times into different cells en mass?* yes it is. Check [Text To Columns](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7). Probably you could split your data using `-` as separator.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I've added a cell example if this is of any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try, formatted as Time:

```
=MID(A1,7,5)-LEFT(A1,5)
```

If that does not work then check for leading spaces. Won't suit if times are late/early order, nor if spanning midnight.

Edited so there should be no need to strip out `'text'`.